How to prove $a_{-k} = b_{k}^{*}$?
When I look a book about classical field theory, I find a equation
\begin{align*}
(a_{-k} - b_{k}^{*})\exp[-i\omega t] + (b_{-k} - a_{k}^{*})\exp[i\omega t] = 0 \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where $ a,b $ is constant which is reletive about $ k $, and $ \omega $ is a constant, $ t $ is variable $ t \in \mathbb{R} $, $ * $ is represent complex conjugate.
And the book tell me that $ a_{-k} = b_{k}^{*} $. I am not sure that $ \exp[-i\omega t] $ and $ \exp[i\omega t] $ are linearly independent, just like $ 1 $ and $ \cos x $, they are both Legendre polynomial.
Can you help me from equation (1) to prove
\begin{align*}
a_{-k} = b_{k}^{*}
\end{align*}
or tell me this is not rigorous.
Thanks by LiZ.

LiZ, just write $(1)$ for $t=0$ and for $t=\frac\pi{2\omega}$, so you get a system of two equations and then solve it.

@Angelo Thank you very much.
